# EclipseLink throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to weave a class

Tags: jpa, playframework, eclipselink

I've got play framework application (2.3.8) to which I provide eclipselink-2.5.1.jar agent. During startup I see in logs:

> Weaver encountered an exception while trying to weave class
>   [*one of my JPA entities class*].  The exception was:
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 30053

1. How can I investigate what's causing the problem?
2. What might be a problem?

UPDATE:
So changing logging to finest gave me a stack trace:

```
EL Finest]: weaver: 2015-07-16 20:52:31.163--ServerSession(1547425104)--Thread(Thread[application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2,5,main])--java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 25970
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.asm.ClassReader.getInterfaces(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.weaving.ComputeClassWriter.typeImplements(ComputeClassWriter.java:143)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.weaving.ComputeClassWriter.typeImplements(ComputeClassWriter.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.weaving.ComputeClassWriter.getCommonSuperClass(ComputeClassWriter.java:62)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.asm.ClassWriter.getMergedType(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.asm.Frame.merge(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.asm.Frame.merge(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.asm.MethodWriter.visitMaxs(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.asm.MethodAdapter.visitMaxs(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.weaving.MethodWeaver.visitMaxs(MethodWeaver.java:152)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.libraries.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.weaving.PersistenceWeaver.transform(PersistenceWeaver.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JavaSECMPInitializer$1.transform(JavaSECMPInitializer.java:228)
        at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
        at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.security.PrivilegedAccessHelper.getClassForName(PrivilegedAccessHelper.java:124)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.EntityListenerMetadata.getClass(EntityListenerMetadata.java:224)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.listeners.EntityClassListenerMetadata.process(EntityClassListenerMetadata.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor.processListeners(EntityAccessor.java:1220)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.addEntityListeners(MetadataProcessor.java:138)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:591)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:304)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:302)
        at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.em(DefaultJPAApi.java:71)
        at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi.withTransaction(DefaultJPAApi.java:123)
        at play.db.jpa.JPA.withTransaction(JPA.java:159)
        at play.db.jpa.TransactionalAction.call(TransactionalAction.java:16)
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:94)
        at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anonfun$7.apply(JavaAction.scala:94)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
        at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:40)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:70)
        at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext.execute(HttpExecutionContext.scala:32)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$.apply(Future.scala:31)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$.apply(Future.scala:485)
        at play.core.j.JavaAction.apply(JavaAction.scala:94)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105)
        at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:104)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:103)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:103)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:96)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:524)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:524)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:560)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:560)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Iteratee.scala:536)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Iteratee.scala:536)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
        at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

But it isn't much of a help for me.

Comment: Try using the static weaver and turning logging on to finest and see if you get the exception.  see https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Advanced_JPA_Development/Performance/Weaving/Static_Weaving

Comment: Do you have this problem in `dev` (with `activator run`) or only in `prod`?

Comment: Is your configuration similar to what is described here:
https://pbaris.wordpress.com/2013/07/29/play-framework-2-jpa-eclipselink-setup/

Comment: Actually I am not sure how to provide the agent in dev, so I am not sure if problem occurs there. On production I am providing -J-javaagent:/somewhere/org.eclipse.persistence.eclipselink.jar to my start script and that's where problem happens. As for configuration it's quite similar to the one from the link (I use postgresql instead of mysql). By the way, I did not mention it - the persistence works ok, application starts - but there are those errors and the weaving probably does not happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the ASM processor being used by EclipseLink when dealing with lambda expressions.  Bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=429992 is fixed in EclipseLink 2.6.

Comment: It looks like updating EclipseLink solved the problem. It's very likely that issue was caused by the bug you mentioned (but I did not look into it too closly).